# RocksDB fileanme meaning used by Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Under `/tmp/streams-my-application-id`
I found the files that RocksDB uses. My intention was to check the file size by `du -h`.

When seeing the file name, I'm curious about the meaning of file name. What does the file names mean? I suppose it's related to the Kafka Streams tasks and the partitions.

Does the prefix 0 and 1 mean number of topics used, and the later is the partition used?

This KafkaStreams app simply joins two topics using KStream-KTable, and one topic is re-partition and reduce into KTable.

```
8,0K    ./0_2
8,0K    ./0_1
3,1M    ./1_2/rocksdb/KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000002
3,1M    ./1_2/rocksdb
3,1M    ./1_2
3,0M    ./1_0/rocksdb/KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000002
3,0M    ./1_0/rocksdb
3,1M    ./1_0
3,0M    ./1_1/rocksdb/KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000002
3,0M    ./1_1/rocksdb
3,0M    ./1_1
8,0K    ./0_0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File names are derived using sub-topology and partition number.

Usually KStream application is splitted into number of sub-topologies (i.e. Sub-topology 0,1,2....etc).   While using stateful transformation, state-store directories use that 
reference in order to generate the directory and file name like given below:

```
<sub-topology-number>_<partition_number>
```

So first number represents sub-topology and second one represents partition number

```
8,0K    ./0_2    //directory
8,0K    ./0_1    // diretory
3,1M    ./1_2/rocksdb/KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000002
```

And `KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000002` format is

```
<Processor Node Type>-<Processor Node number>
```

Comment: can you please also provide the link to the documentation as reference?

Comment: This is internal details and there is no documentation.

Comment: In other words, what @MatthiasJ.Sax is saying: There's no contract or guarantee that the current naming scheme will be followed in future Kafka releases. If you decide to build functionality against the current naming scheme, you are doing this at your own risk.